# iTunes itself running as a background process

Tags: itunes, windows-10-v1607

Ever since I installed the Windows 10 Anniversary Update iTunes on my PC doesn't work and the uninstaller and installer don't work either.

 I deleted the iTunes folders and the others suggested by Apple for the uninstall of iTunes here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204275


According to Task Manager the installer is running as a background process (just like iTunes was before I deleted the files):


[iTunes installer running as a Background process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71IJd.png)

> Update: I tried using another application (WizTree) and that is also running in the background.

Comment: Give her a shot man :) http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html

Comment: Based on the issues you're experiencing, I would suggest we first attempt to perform an Anti-Virus scan, any applications should be able to detect a virus. I am not stating iTunes and the other application are virus, but _perhaps_ the virus is causing the system to play up. Care to perform a quick scan for us?

Comment: @MichaelNancarrow I tried running a scan with windows defender but the scanning window only showed an empty progress bar but nothing was going on. This happened for both the quick and full scan

Comment: @MichaelNancarrow The antivirus check worked! Could you please repost as an answer?